# Publish releases to gh-pages with travis without deleting previous releases

Tags: github, webpack, travis-ci, github-pages, yarnpkg

I want to publish releases to gh-pages. The deploy provider can be configured to keep history using `keep-history: true`. However I would like previous versions not to be just available in the git history but not to be deleted from the repository.

I've configured yarn and webpack to create a separate directory for each tag and to put the distribution in both a "latest"-directory as well as this tag specific directory. I would like to see a tag directory for all previous versions and not just for the latest version.

Here are the results of my current configuration: https://github.com/retog/rdfgraphnode-rdfext/tree/gh-pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following solution.

In `travis.yml` replace:

```
- provider: pages
  skip-cleanup: true
  github-token: $GITHUB_TOKEN
  keep-history: true
  local-dir: distribution
  on:
    tags: true
```

With:

```
- provider: script
  script: bash .travis_publish
  on:
    tags: true
```

And add the script file `.travis_publish` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
PUBLICATION_BRANCH=gh-pages
# Checkout the branch
REPO_PATH=$PWD
pushd $HOME
git clone --branch=$PUBLICATION_BRANCH    https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/$TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG publish 2>&1 > /dev/null
cd publish
# Update pages
cp -r $REPO_PATH/distribution .
# Commit and push latest version
git add .
git config user.name  "Travis"
git config user.email "travis@travis-ci.org"
git commit -m "Updated distribution."
git push -fq origin $PUBLICATION_BRANCH 2>&1 > /dev/null
popd
```

Comment: For reasons I don't understand on another repo I had to add the suffix ".git" in the repo URL when doing the clone: `git clone --branch=$PUBLICATION_BRANCH https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/$TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG.git publish`

Comment: Doesn't work anymore :(
`cp: cannot stat '/home/travis/build/username/[secure]/distribution': No such file or directory`

Comment: Nevermind the above comment, `distribution` is the path you might like to publish from your git repo. Another script https://github.com/voorhoede/front-end-tooling-recipes/blob/master/travis-deploy-to-gh-pages/scripts/deploy.sh